# How to cycle array enumeration in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumerator

I want to implement such enumerator that rewinds from last back to first element and continues looping, such an infinite loop. How could it be done?

Comment: Ruby's methods are appropriately named:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method that does exactly that:

[Enumerable#cycle](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle)

```
>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>> a.cycle.first(7)
=> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: I would say it's better to define it as `a = [1,2,3].cycle` then call `a.first 7`, `a.next` or `a.rewind` etc.